# Algorithm to find subset of integers with highest sum under specific conditions

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of N>1 integers all greater than 1, not necessarily all different.
I need the most effective algorithm to find a subset of these numbers whose sum is the greatest. Unfortunately, there are some rules according to which some sets can't be chosen and verifying these rules is computationally long. Therefore I need the best way to examine the smallest number of sets and be sure to pick the set, among the allowed ones, that has the biggest sum. To be precise, what i really need is the sum itself, so if there is more than a subset that has the biggest possible sum, i don't care to have them all, I need just the value of the sum.
 - If a subset is not allowed, all of the other subset that contain it are not allowed. 
 - If a subset is allowed, all its subset are also allowed.
 - If a subset is allowed, nothing can be said about the subsets that contain it.
 - If a subset is no allowed, nothing can be said about its subset (i.e., all its subset could be allowed or some, or none)
 - All subset with 1 element are allowed.

Let's see an example. Let's say the numbers are A = 10, B = 5, C = 4, D = 1.
Let's say i find out that AB is not allowed as a set. Then also ABCD, ABC, ABD are not allowed. The highest sum that i could find is now 15, because there is at least a subset (ACD) whose sum is 15. If i check and find that ACD is allowed then i indeed found that 15 is the sum i was looking for. Otherwise, i could test BCD but its sum is only 10, like A. I still have to try AC (=14) because it can be higher than BCD. I don't have to test AD if AC is valid, because surely AD it is smaller than AC, and so on and so on...;

As you can see, there is room for some smart optimization: i need to limit as much as possible the check to see if a given subset is valid (calculating the sum is, of course, just a sum and is not computationally important).

I think i am not the first one that needs such an algorithm but i couldnt find anything online.
Thanks

Wentu

Comment: Is the allowedness of a set really just an arbitrary query that you know nothing else about in advance?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to use Boolean algebra.

For example, given $A=10, B=5, C=4, D=1, E=1, F=2, G=7$ with $AB, DG,$ and $AG$ disallowed:

We can say that our disallowed combinations look like $(AB + DG + AG)'$. ($XY$ means $X \text{ and } Y$. $X + Y$ means $X \text{ or } Y$. $X'$ means $\text{not } X$.)

Applying [de Morgan's Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html) and distributing when necessary:

$$\begin{align}
& (AB + DG + AG)'\\
& (AB)'(DG)'(AG)'\\
& (A' + B')(D' + G')(A' + G')\\
& (A'D' + A'G' + B'D' + B'G')(A' + G')\\
& A'D' + A'D'G' + A'G' + A'B'D' + B'D'G' + A'B'G' + B'G'\\
& A'D'(1 + G' + B') + A'G' + B'D'G' + A'B'G' + B'G\\
& A'D' + G'(A' + B'D' + A'B' + B')\\
& A'D' + G'(A' + B'(D' + A' + 1))\\
& A'D' + G'(A' + B')\\
& A'D' + A'G' + B'G'
\end{align}$$

In other words, you can discard either $AD, AG,$ or $BG$.

$A+D=11;\quad A+G=17;\quad B+G=12$

So it looks like you can discard $AD$ with the least impact to the overall sum. Discarding $A$ and $D$ leaves you with $B, C, E, F,$ and $G$.

$B+C+E+F+G = 5 + 4 + 1 + 2 + 7 = 19$. So $19$ is the maximum sum in this example.

Comment: Scott, first of all thank you for your detailed answer. It seems a good approach if i knew in advance that AB, DG, AG are not allowed.
My problem is that, in your example, what i know is just that i have ABCDEFG and their values and it is costly to know if AB is allowed or not, if DG is allowed or not and so on for whichever subset. The cost of calculating if a subset is allowed or not is *roughly* linear on the cardinality of the subset, that is, in general, it costs me twice as much to calculate if ABCD is allowed than to calculate if, say, BE is allowed.

Comment: I need a strategy to find the max sum for an allowed set by doing the least possible amount of checks on subsets.
If i have N numbers, I have 2^N-1 subsets. All of the numbers are allowed subsets so the bigger of them is the min. sum that i will find. I could start "top to bottom" by checkin the subset with N elements: if it is allowed i finished and found the biggest sum. If it is not, i have to check many of the subsets with N-1 element but i can't be sure that if i find an allowed subset with 3 elements this will have a sum that is bigger than any possible sum for a subset with 2 elements.

Comment: In my previous example, if BCD (3 elements) is allowed it has sum = 10 but there is the subset AD (2 elements) with sum 11 > 10.
If i start bottom to top, i can check all the N(N-1)/2 subset with two elements and for each subset that is not allowed i can clear all the subsets with more elements that contain the non-allowed subset (example, if i find that AD is not allowed, i can eliminate also ABCD, ABD, ACD).

Comment: So in your answer the problem is that i don't know in advance that only certain subset are not allowed... i have to search for them and i need to check the minimum possibile number of time. For instance, if i know that BCD is allowed i won't check DB, DC, BC because their sum is surely less than that of BCD, but i still need to check AB,AC,AD, in this order, so that if i find that one of them is allowed, i don't need to check the rest (because i know in advance that AB>AC>AD).
I hope i managed to better convey the nature of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an idea of your values ?

N is 100, 1000, 10000 ?

Imagine you test all subsets with 2 integers, which proportion of them will be allowed ?  20% or 99% ?

Imagine you test all subsets with 10 integers, which proportion of them will be allowed ?  5% or 50% ?

If the proportion of subsets which are allowed is known by advance (not exact value, just an approximate value), I am pretty sure it can help.

Comment: This is asking for clarification on the problem, it should be a comment.